# Zurb-foundation: Using divs inside of a label tag

Tags: zurb-foundation

i am using [foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com/) for my first project right now and i really love the functionality it provides out of the box, **but** i am having trouble with my custom radio boxes.

The idea is to not only have text inside of the radio buttons label, but also an image and some bold text.
As soon as i start using either an *img* or a *bold* tag inside of the label, the radio button selection via the labels text is broken.

The code i am using is this

```
<label for="radio2">
    <img src="img/nho_musicians_flute.png">
    <input name="radio2" type="radio" id="radio2" style="display:none;" CHECKED>
    <span class="custom radio checked"></span>
    <b>Radio</b> Button 1
</label>
```

With this it is only possible to select a radio box by clicking on it DIRECTLY, clicking the text or the image results in erratic selections, it seems that the foundation JS selectors didn't account for extra tags inside of a label.

Is there a way to make this work with foundation, or do i have to resort to workarounds (making the whole text bold and put the image outside of the label)?

Comment: Please upload a snapshot of what you want to do, and what you are getting at the moment

Comment: Thanks, but the solution by am_ looks promising. In the end i used a workaround.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good question, I had the same issues as you when I needed to create custom forms through F4's custom form implementations.

If you look in the implementation (custom.forms.scss) you can see that they use the `:before` and `content: ""` in order to be able to achieve this. I suspect that's why you can't add any tags after the `<span class="custom radio"></span>`

Now what you CAN do as a workaround is to place your custom elements etc inside the `<span>` element. This will work just fine, but will look wierd as the width and height is very small. But from then on its just a matter of styling it until you get it to look as you want. Here is a really simple example using absolute positioning:

```
<span class="custom radio">
   <span style="position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; width: 500px; margin-left: 30px;">
      <b>test</b> foo
   </span>
</span> &nbsp;
```

Comment: Thanks, i have to admit that i did not check the scss, i just tried to figure out their selectors by analyzing the js.Your solution looks promising, althoug i already used a different workaround, with just triggering the radio buttons with js when the image that i added just before the span was clicked. I will give your solution a try and then use it next time, as it is a cleaner solution that doesn't need JS.